# Отправка формы ajax на сервер

Tags: ajax, laravel

Помогите решить вопрос... В форме при клике на add-name добавляются инпуты, как отправить полностью всю форму с их значениями ?

```
<form method="POST" id="formx" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="send()">
   <label for="name">Название приглашения:</label><br>
   <input id="name"  type="text"><br>
   <label for="name">Текст приглашения:</label>
   <textarea rows="10" cols="100%" id="text" type="text"></textarea>
       <div class="input-holder">
         <input id="pole" type="text" class="text guests-input"  placeholder="Введите имя гостя">
             <a href="#" class="add-name">+</a>
       </div>
         <input value="Добавить людей" type="submit">
</form>

$(document).on('click', '.add-name', function(){
    var cloned = $(this).parent().clone();
    cloned.find('input').attr('value', '').val('').addClass('new');
    $(this).parent().parent().append(cloned);
    return false;
});


function send() {
  var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var text = $('#text').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{route('inivation.store')}}',
      data: {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, name, text},
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну я всю форму отправлял так

```
function send() {
$("#formx").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '{{route('inivation.store')}}',
        data: $('#formx').serialize(), 
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
           alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: А как в этом запросе еще передать CSRF_TOKEN ?

Comment: @Федотов попробуйте так как исправил
у меня не надо было вставлять токен так как он был в форме (писал на django)

Comment: хотя может в php не так формируется он, попробуйте просто в headers указать его без функции getCookie просто headers: {var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}

Comment: Не хочет работать, требует токен, я обычно его передавал в data, можно его туда впихнуть ? data: $this.serialize(), + токен, только как ? не силен в ajax

Comment: @Федотов попробуй так как исправил (возможно место &token названия name вашего токена )

Comment: Отправляется только токен...

Comment: @Федотов а вы где токен храните? 
просто его не вижу в форме

Comment: var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
Форма отправляет только параметр _token h65Mgqpmx82JwrlwYgAF6ZtkwZdLdY018h9exDyf

Comment: Потестил код на другом сервере без laravel, токен удалил но в параметрах пусто

Comment: @Федотов ну там же вроде надо токен на странице добавлять в форму  как-то так {{csrf_token()}}
или в meta как-то так  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
Нет?

Comment: @Федотов в форме не вижу
у вас в meta значит? 
если так то попробуйте сделать то что я поправил

Comment: Добавил, изменений нет, я Вам говорю что скрипт на сервер без laravel тестировал, там токен не нужен и форма отправляется но в параметрах пусто

Comment: @Федотов попробуйте сейчас, если не поможет тогда уже не знаю чем помочь

Comment: @Федотов хотя если вы делали полный копипаст то в принципе понятно, у вас было в onsubmit="send()" и он просто не находил эту функицию

Comment: @Федотов чтобы предыдущая сработала скорее всего хватит удалить  onsubmit="send()"

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Федотов помогло?
и с csrf тоже?

Comment: Все заработало, в самой форме был косяк...

Comment: @Федотов рад был помочь)
можете закрывать вопрос)